# Cannot make Scanner String method work

Tags: java, string, methods

I'm trying to create a Scanner method for strings that returns the value entered by the user only if it is not blank (whitespace, user hitting 'enter' immediately etc..). If the user does this I want to print out an error message and have the loop return to the beginning again and await a new user input. If correct, I want the method to return the correct input value.

My code is as such:

```html
private static final Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);

private static String readString(){
  while(true){
   String command = scr.next();
   if(command != null && !command.trim().isEmpty()){
    return command;
   }
   System.out.println("You have to type something");
  }
 }
```

Right now when I run this method in other methods if I leave a blank or simply hit 'enter' my output simply leaves a blank space until I type a string such as 'abc'. Then it returns that value.

Any helpful advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Replace `src.next()` with `src.nextLine()`

```
private static final Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(readString());
}
private static String readString() {
    while (true) {
        String command = scr.nextLine();
        if (command != null && !command.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return command;
        }
        System.out.println("You have to type something");
    }
}
```

Comment: @osmark86 no problems ;) and eventually, all solutions to problems are simple... once you have found them :P